# Bootstrap 4 Modal Will Not Open on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I can not get my modal to open. I tried just the plain HTML found on the Bootstrap 4 site and then used some Javascript. I really can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated!

`enter code here`<

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-centered  boxes" id="box1">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="box1modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">

    See More

  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">

          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Wedding Invites</h5>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

          </button>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <img src="Wedding%20Invites.jpg">


        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
 `enter code here`<script type="text/javascript">
```

`enter code here` $("#box1modal").click(function(event){
 `enter code here`$('#myModal').modal('show');
    `enter code here`  )};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using bootstrap no need of extra scripting.bootstrap itself provides its scripts to run different  animations and actions. I checked your code.
The error lies in line

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="box1modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
```

See you've set data target as #exampleModal while id of your modal is "myModal". Just change above code to

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="box1modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

And it will work fine without any other script.
Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked! I can not believe I spent so much time trying to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

You have given the data target as examplemodal and the id of div as mymodal. Both should have been the same, thats the issue.

Answer (score -1):

i test your code , every things  fine just you have to make sure

1) add references
2) your code must be inside  $(document).ready(function(){ ---- }

```
<html>
<head> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="col-sm-3 col-centered  boxes" id="box1">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="box1modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">

    See More

  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">

          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Wedding Invites</h5>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

          </button>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <img src="Wedding%20Invites.jpg">


        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>


</body>
</hmtl>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#box1modal').click(function(){
alert("btn click")
$('#myModal').modal('show')
});

});

</script>
```